# R extract everything after = regex

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a bunch of urls in a column and I need to create a new variable to extract a specific unique id for each url. The unique id occurs after the equal sign. For example:

https://website.com/locationDetails.php?l=29A5CDCA-7D0F-4FAA-906C-00DA90EBFD13

So the unique id variable would be: 29A5CDCA-7D0F-4FAA-906C-00DA90EBFD13

I think I can do this with str_extract using the regex

```
data %>% 
  mutate(unique_id = str_extract(url, " "))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all URLs would only ever have *one* query parameters, you may use `sub` here:

```r
url <- "https://website.com/locationDetails.php?l=29A5CDCA-7D0F-4FAA-906C-00DA90EBFD13"
param <- sub("^.*=", "", url)
param

[1] "29A5CDCA-7D0F-4FAA-906C-00DA90EBFD13"
```

Assuming there could be multiple query parameters, and you want the one labelled as `l`, then we can use `sub` with a capture group:

```r
url <- "https://website.com/locationDetails.php?l=29A5CDCA-7D0F-4FAA-906C-00DA90EBFD13"
param <- sub("^.*\\bl=(.*?)(?=&|$)", "\\1", url, perl=TRUE)
param

[1] "29A5CDCA-7D0F-4FAA-906C-00DA90EBFD13"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_extract` -

```
url <- 'https://website.com/locationDetails.php?l=29A5CDCA-7D0F-4FAA-906C-00DA90EBFD13'
stringr::str_extract(url, '(?<==).*')
#[1] "29A5CDCA-7D0F-4FAA-906C-00DA90EBFD13"
```

which is same as

```
stringr::str_match(url, '=(.*)')[, 2]
```

Comment: Does adding '=(.*)$' is redundant because * already matches everything?

Comment: Maybe yes, that is redundant but I think it is also safer .

Answer (score 0):

- match everything upto first `=` and capture everything in a group after that.

```r
str <- 'https://website.com/locationDetails.php?l=29A5CDCA-7D0F-4FAA-906C-00DA90EBFD13'

gsub('^[^\\=]*\\=(.*)$', '\\1', str)
#> [1] "29A5CDCA-7D0F-4FAA-906C-00DA90EBFD13"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>